# How to GROUP BY with a CASE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My SQL example is as follows...

```
DECLARE @a TABLE(
    id INT,
    val BIT
);
INSERT INTO @a(id,val) VALUES (1,0),(2,0),(3,1),(4,0),(5,1);

SELECT
    id = CASE
        WHEN val = 1 THEN id
        ELSE MAX(id)
    END
FROM @a
WHERE val = 0
GROUP BY id, val;
```

What my result is:

```
id
---
 1
 2
 4
```

What I am trying to get...

```
id
---
 4
```

Or if I did "WHERE val = 1" then what I want is...

```
id
---
 3
 5
```

What I'm basically trying to say is "if I'm selecting where val = 1, I want all the rows, but if I'm selecting where val = 0 I only want the row with the highest id". Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. Why is there only 1 row when val = 0 but you want both when val = 1??? That doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: What I'm basically trying to say is "if val = 1, I want all the rows, but if val = 0 i only want the row with the highest id". I'll put that in my question, thank you.

Comment: I think you have simplified your example so much it doesn't represent the problem anymore.

Comment: @SeanLange -- It doesn't make sense -- but I manged to come up with a solution!

Comment: @Hogan I saw that. I was thinking also of two statements but it is so far from anything logical I didn't post it. :)

Comment: @SeanLange - well one of us has no shame.  I know for sure this is not the "correct" or "standard" practice -- but I can't know the right answer without knowing what the OP is actually trying to do.

Comment: @Hogan I did not intend at all for that sound the way you interpreted it. My apologies. Stupid internet and not being able to hear inflection.

Comment: @SeanLange - lol - no worries -- I'm way beyond having anything said on SO hurt my feelings.  I'm all about answering un-answerable questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand what you are trying to do, but the following query gives the expected result with `WHERE val = 1` or `WHERE val = 0`. The idea is to move the case to the `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM @a
WHERE val = 1
GROUP BY CASE WHEN val = 1 THEN id ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: This is a really curious solution and I like it a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @felloffthestack I'd go with this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UNION statement to combine tables.  So if we split what you want to do into two select statements we get the following if the WHERE = 0

```
SELECT MAX(id) 
FROM @a
GROUP BY ID, VAL

UNION

SELECT ID
FROM @a
WHERE val = 0 AND val = 1
GROUP BY ID, VAL
```

And the following if the WHERE = 1

```
SELECT MAX(id) 
FROM @a
GROUP BY ID, VAL

UNION

SELECT ID
FROM @a
WHERE val = 1 AND val = 1
GROUP BY ID, VAL
```

This **might** make clear why changing the where clause to have it do something different seems strange to me.  Clearly in the first one the part after the union is silly/useless.  In the 2nd it also seems strange to have the same expression twice in the where clause.  But this meets your requirements to change one value in a where and have two different results.

Maybe you can explain your requirements better now that you see the solution?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure I'm explaining it as clearly as I should, but @JamieD77 found the solution I was looking for.